# Best Practice for loading non-existent data

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I'm trying to build a table in MS SQL 2008, loaded with roughly 50,000 rows of data.  Right now I'm doing something like:

```
Create Table MyCustomData
(
ColumnKey Int Null,
Column1 NVarChar(100) Null,
Column2 NVarChar(100) Null

Primary Key Clustered
(
ColumnKey ASC
)
WITH (
PAD_INDEX  = OFF, 
STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, 
IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, 
ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, 
ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON
)
)

CREATE INDEX IDX_COLUMN1 ON MyCustomData([COLUMN1])
CREATE INDEX IDX_COLUMN2 ON MyCustomData([COLUMN2])

DECLARE @MyCount Int

SET @MyCount = 0

WHILE @MyCount < 50000
BEGIN
 INSERT INTO MyCustomData
 (ColumnKey, Column1, Column2)
 Select @MyCount + 1, 'Custom Data 1', 'Custom Data 2'

Set @MyCount = @MyCount + 1
END
```

My problem is that this is crazy slow.  I thought at one point I could create a Select Statement to build my custom data and use that as the datasource for my Insert Into statement.

i.e. something like

```
INSERT INTO MyCustomData
 (ColumnKey, Column1, Column2)
From (Select Top 50000 Row_Count(), 'Custom Data 1', 'Custom Data 2')
```

I know this doesn't work, but its the only thing I can show that seems to provide an example of what I'm after.  Any suggestions would be greatly appriciated.

Comment: @Aizotu: You want the 50000 rows to have same data `('Custom Data 1', 'Custom Data 2')` ?

Comment: I think he wants to have some "fake-data" for testing purposes.

Comment: @Tim: I would guess so too, but the script doesn't show any signs of that.

Comment: @ypercube: the title has a sign: "non-existent data"

Comment: @Aizotu - Part of your slowness may be that you are inserting through 3 indexes...don't add the nonclustered ones til you are finished inserting.

Comment: This isn't for testing purposes.  My post was to convey a T-SQL scripted process that's running slow using all the same mechanics.  It's not exactly fake data that I'll be using in production. The 'Custom Data 1' and 'Custom Data 2' values are just substitutions of proprietiry code. The key point is that I don't have those values coming from any specific data source.  they are generated values.   I'm not pulling data from any SQL tables to populate the "MyCustomData" table.

Comment: @JNK - Thanks.  That's a good point.  I was planning on moving the index building off to the end of the script.  Simply inheriting code so I'm trying to be cautious and come up with a variety of solutions to the performance issues we're having with this.

Comment: @Aizotu - are those data fields using scalar functions, by any chance?

Comment: @JNK - Um.  Yes.  yes they are.  Why do you seem doom and gloom in that question?  ;-p

Comment: Scalar functions are notorious performance bottlenecks.  The functions are probably the source of your issue(s).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, if I wanted 50000 rows with constant data and a counter, I'd go

```
select row_number() over(order by t1.[number]), 'Custom data 1', 'Custom data 2'
from
  master..spt_values as t1
  cross join (select [number] from master..spt_values where [type] = 'P' and [number] between 1 and 50) as t2
where
  [type] = 'P' and t1.[number] between 1 and 1000
```

Comment: I like this a lot!  I need to make sure that at each customer site, the application that runs this T-SQL has access to the master database and the spt_values table.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2011/02/01/sample-datasets-for-benchmarking-and-testing/

some sample datasets for testing.

Another option would be to create your data in a csv file using a language of your choice then import that into the SQL Server which would be much faster than your current method.